# Are real-time OSDs for HD FPV video systems available for drones?

Tags: first-person-view, osd

In the last several years, several high-definition FPV video systems have become available. These systems do not use the NTSC or PAL analog video historically used with FPV systems and they are not compatible with the OSD systems, including some that are extremely sophisticated, customizable, and open-source, and are meant for use with analog standard-def video.

Are sophisticated, customizable OSD systems able to receive data from off-the-shelf flight controllers and to overlay data and graphics such as artificial horizons, altimeters, compasses, home pointers, etc on an HD video feed commercially available for hobbyists (outside of pre-built drone systems)?

Answer (score 3):

One of the most popular HD FPV systems out as of writing is [from DJI](https://www.dji.com/fpv?site=brandsite&from=nav). The DJI Air unit, which serves as the VTX on the multirotor, [has integration with Betaflight](https://www.dji.com/fpv/info#specs) over a UART port on the flight controller which it uses to implement the Betaflight OSD.

I don't have one, so I can't confirm, but I believe most of the OSD elements available for the analog OSD are also available in the DJI system. (*cit. [UAVFutures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-xSZTftr0w)*) Joshua Bardwell on YouTube has [a video listing out which OSD elements the DJI OSD supports](https://youtu.be/L7Pag_gDKWA?t=102).

- Angle: Pitch/Roll
- Battery average cell voltage
- Battery current draw
- Battery current mAh drawn
- Battery voltage
- Disarmed
- ESC temperature
- Fly mode
- GPS latitude/longitude
- GPS stats
- PID pitch/roll/yaw
- Power
- Profile: PID and rate
- RSSI value
- RTC date and time

More element support may have been added since Bardwell's video was released in December 2019. Configuration of the layout of elements on the screen is supported through the OSD tab in the Betaflight configurator.

Comment: Does DJI have a video showing these parameters?

Comment: I don't believe so. They have support listed on their specs page, linked in my answer, but I don't think they have a video about it.

Answer (score 1):

As of the writing of this question 2020-04-19,  the only viable HD FPV system is the DJI system which has proprietary firmware and does NOT offer the ability to inject any custom OSD via a third-party system.

Comment: Doesn't that contradict what @ifconfig said?

What happened to the Connex Prosight?

Comment: It is widely accepted that every system that came before DJI's system (including Connex Prosight) is not practically useable.   Either too much latency or other video breakup problems prohibited widespread adoption.  So my answer assumes that DJI's system is the only currently viable HD system.

Comment: Interesting. I knew the Connex Prosight was shortish range and considered somewhat experimental, but didn't know it was that bad. Of course, everything is still Too Expensive.